# Can't connect to Android device

Tags: android, adb

I've got a problem with my phone. I've got HTC One M7 with GPE ROM, that I installed some days ago (ROM of course). When I'm trying to connect to computer and debug my app, in ADB my phone is shown as a offline.

[image]
Also when I'm trying to display connected devices (with `adb devices` command) there is information that my phone is offline.

[image]

I've propably tried everything.

- I restarted server with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.
- I tried to restart phone and PC.
- I also tried toggle on/off debugging options several times.
- I even tried to factory reset my phone and nothing helped. What is wired, I noticed that after factory reset, when I was trying to connect phone to PC for the first time, there was no "RSA key dialog" that should pop-up on my phone. I remember that before I installed GPE ROM, I had Stock ROM and back then debugging was wroking properly. What is more interesting every time when I plugging in my phone to PC, in `C:\Users\*username*\.android` are being created 2 files: adbkey and adbkey.pub and I don't know where is it coming from because there is no `adb_key` file in `data/misc/adb` folder in my HTC device.

I completly don't know what
   to do, because I literally did everyting I read in the Internet and
   nothing works. I have feeling that my problem could be with RSA key,
   maybe somewhere in memory is old file that was used to authorize when
   I had old ROM installed, but I don't know how to remove it, because
   as I said before there is no adb_key file in phone memory.

- I also downloaded "WiFI ADB" app from Play Store and I tried to
  connect with `adb connect IP_ADDRESS:PORT` but I get this response:
  unable to connect to IP_ADDRESS:PORT
- Also I'd like to add that I
  can see my phone as a mass storage.
- Also I updated HTC USB drivers.

Comment: Have you tried using another phone or switching usb ports? your issue may be device specific

Comment: I tried switching usb ports, it didn't works. I'm going to try with another PC and another phone to check where the problem is.

Comment: any luck? im looking for other incantations to get my phone to connect.

Comment: @dcsan I insalled another ROM on my phone and only that helped.